# Attached is my thoughts. Plural or singular?

Tags: grammatical-number

In an email I wrote :

> Attached is my thoughts.

And then thought about it.

My attachment is a singular attachment. My thoughts are in the plural, within the single attachment.

But the very fact that I thought about it makes me wonder if this is one of those occasions when, whatever the formal and technical condition may be, the psychology of the statement overrides.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Related: [“Attached {is/are} X, Y and Z." If X, Y and Z are all singular, is it correct to use "is" here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162442/attached-is-are-x-y-and-z-if-x-y-and-z-are-all-singular-is-it-correct-to)

Comment: @sumelic Are you conveying that my own sentence is also a case of subject inversion ?

Comment: I don’t know, but based on F.E.’s answer I would say yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, as far as I know:

"Attached are my thoughts."

Same as "My thoughts are attached."
(That's simple present tense in passive).

Or better

"Find attached my thoughts."

But

"Attached is my document"

same as:

"My document/ file is attached"

or better:

"find attached my document.

Comment: While I agree, why?

Comment: @psosuna:  subject/verb agreement.

Comment: @Wordster No, I know why, but is it in the answer?

Comment: @psosuna:  sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Wordster Sorry, I'll be clear: I agree with this answer, but it doesn't answer the reason why this is the answer. We both know it's because of subject/verb agreement with respect to pluralization, but since it's a string of examples, I'm not sure that the answer is really answering the question by explaining rather than answering by example.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of “thought” - [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/thought?q=thoughts) with grammatical numbers:

> the act of thinking about something to form ideas and opinions, or an
> idea or opinion produced by thinking:

As in:

> [ U ] I have given this matter considerable thought.
>
> [ C ] Do you have any thoughts on what we should do now?

and

> [ C ] Attached are my thought**s**

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to find the answer here is to shift the words - **"My thoughts are attached."**

"Attached" isn't plural or singular. This may have been a different question if you used the word *attachment*, but, as it stands, the word *thoughts* is the only possible subject of the sentence.