# Is a copy vs are copies

Tags: grammar

I am attaching one copy of three different documents to an email.  Do I say "Attached is a copy of the last 3 documents" or "Attached are copies of the last 3 documents?"

Comment: How many attachments are there?

Comment: "Attached are copies of the last 3 documents?" would be most idiomatic.

Comment: ...unless "one copy of three documents" means you pressed the 'continue' button on the copier to make one document comprising all three individual ones, hence my request for clarification. Is that one copy of all three together, or one copy of each?

Comment: Unless there is a single attachment, I don't see the value of specifying **one** copy over *a copy* (or *copies*). It's easy for the recipient to make copies of an electronic document. Attaching multiple copies of the same document serves no purpose, so why say "one"?

Comment: This question is very similar: ["Attached {is/are} X, Y and Z." If X, Y and Z are all singular, is it correct to use "is" here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162442/attached-is-are-x-y-and-z-if-x-y-and-z-are-all-singular-is-it-correct-to)

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm guessing they're talking about email attachments, not physical copies. But even if it were a zip file containing the 3 documents, I'd agree with Hot Licks. "Attached is a zip file with copies of the last 3 documents".